# sharing problem-set notebooks without answers

Tags: education

I am looking for advice from instructors who provide students with problem sets in Mathematica.  I have problem-set notebooks with prepared answers, which I edit fairly often.  I'm seeking a best practice for sharing the notebooks sans answers.  Here is one possible approach: let each problem be a section, and each answer be a unique (or tagged) subsection of that section.  To produce the problem set programmatically, copy the notebook file to a new name, open it (with `NotebookOpen`), use `Cells` to create a list of all the subsection cells, sequentially select and delete all the subsection groups, and save the resulting notebook.  I am interested in recommended document structures and conversion approaches that others have actually used.

Comment: Being a scientist in industry, I've never had to use MMA in this way, but just shooting in the dark, could [`Encrypt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Encrypt.html)ion be of any use?

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable approach to me: use `CellTags` to identify the answer cells (or cell groups). It will make it easy to programmatically remove them.  Cell tags can also be edited using the GUI.